# Why aren't all functions displayed in the Record Heap Allocation?

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, heap-memory

I recorded the heap allocation so that I could take note of how much memory Javascript functions took. Using the Chrome Developer Tools I headed towards the Memory tab and selected Record allocation profile. There were several functions listed but surprisingly not all of them, and I know that all of them were called since I attached a log to all of them and they all appear in the CPU profiler where I could take note of their execution time. Surprisingly, it does not always provide the same result, sometimes function logOut appears and sometimes it does not. The other functions that I want them to appear have to be visible under logOut.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or even any solutions?

Edit:

May it be the case that a certain function call doesn't consume any memory?

In the case below, another function saveItem is called in logOut so it is supposed to appear under it. Can it be that save Item did not consume any memory? The total memory of logOut can be summed up from the total memory of getlogOutLocalStorage, in that case saveItem consumes 0. Am I getting something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can only guess: 1) yes, it's possible, 2) no, it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: If a function does not allocate any memory, like for example creation of an array or object, is it marked as 0? Because I think I'm not understanding this concept.